# Jupyter lots of X11 subdirectories X11/X11/X11/

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I seem to have a large amount of X11 directories from Jupyter. At first I thought there is an infinite amount, but it ends with:
`/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/bin/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11/X11`
How does this happen? Every X11 folder seems to have the same content as the bin folder itself. The last folder seems similar, but has no X11 subdirectory anymore. The overall size of the X11 folder is roughtly 13GB which seems a lot to me. Is this normal? I installed jupyter on ubuntu using apt. I have a python and a lua (ilua) kernel installed, nothing more. Had some trouble setting it up, would not necessarily like to remove it and breaking even more. For now I can leave it like that, but I would really like to know whats going on there. I found no similar issues online.

Comment: They're not real directories. Instead, they're the result of `ln -s . X11`. So it _is_ infinite, except for tool limitations preventing recursion from continuing.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_. As more of a "why are UNIX tools showing me this output?" question than anything that's _really_ specific to Python or Jupyter, this is better suited to [unix.se] (and also, to be answerable, it needs to include details on _which_ UNIX tools; how you installed Jupyter, which distro you're running, &c also wouldn't be amiss).

Comment: (When re-asking somewhere this is on-topic, be sure to show the methodology for how you determined that 13GB stated size; if your tooling is recursing and double-counting content every iteration, well, there you are)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understood https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic differently. Also there are a ton of questions about commands, files, symbolic links and so on here.
At first I also thought it might be a symbolic link, but does not seem to be the case. I dont think the ubuntu shell has such an early limitation for subdirectories. `du -h` and the ubuntu disk usage analyzer both yield around 16GB (was wront earlier) and it decreases by roughtly 400MB for each subdirectory I go into.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have to disagree. Stack Overflow is not strictly about writing code. The difference may seem subtle, but it is about the creation of software and that also includes the use of programming tools. Jupyter is one of them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see you updated your comment. I installed it using aptas mentioned before. I dont know what more to tell about the installation process. I dont really know what more to provide here. And I dont think there is a lot of ambiguity if I say that there is a limited amount of directories. I dont see how it would be possible for a tool to have a recursion in here.
About symbolic links: running `ls` shows X11 in blue. `find . -type l -ls` yields nothing. So I dont think it can be a symbolic link.

Comment: @KlausD., yes, Jupyter is a programming tool, but the problem isn't meaningfully specific to Jupyter is any way. This `ln -s . X11` practice has been around in Linux packaging as a compatibility shim literally for decades; I remember seeing it in the late 90s, _long_ before Jupyter (or IPython Notebook, or even IPython) ever existed.

Comment: @user84037, hm. Could be that someone archived/copied/packaged a directory structure that originally contained a symlink with symlink-unaware tools, causing it to be transformed from a symlink to a real directory. That would be a packaging bug, if so, something to report to the folks who built whichever Jupyter package you're using.